# Get undefined on the Datakey value in javascript when browsing in IE9

Tags: javascript, asp.net, internet-explorer

I have webpage in which the javascript is worked fine on IE7. Now we have to use IE9 and the page doesn't work. On the page we store datakey in datagrid as a cookie by using javascipt. However the javascript get the value of datakey is undefined.  Would someone tell me how to solve the problem. Thanks in advance.

There is aspx page for the datagrid:

```
    <asp:datagrid id="dgrdLocationWeeks" runat="server" ShowFooter="True"                
           autogeneratecolumns="false"   cssclass="dgrid2" cellpadding="5" width="550" 
          datakeyfield="LocationId">
```

There is the row of datagrid in souce view.

```
<input name="dgrdLocationWeeks$ctl02$chkHideLocation" type="checkbox" 
    id="dgrdLocationWeeks_ctl02_chkHideLocation" locationID="7" />
```

My javascript to get the value of datakey is like that:

```
strHideLocations += document.getElementById(ctrlPrefixName + rowIndex + 
    ctrlSuffixName).locationID
```

I know I can put the datakey into the column, but there are so many datagrid in pages like that.   I think it is better to fix it on javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this for a more browser-friendly method:

```js
var elem = document.getElementById(elemId); //in your case: ctrlPrefixName + rowIndex + ctrlSuffixName
var locID = elem.locationID || elem.getAttribute('locationID');
//alert(locID);
```